# Prove that $τ(m^n)$ and $n$ are coprime $(m,n ∈ N^+)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, arithmetic-functions, primality-test

We have that $τ(n)=\sum_{d|n} 1$ is the number of dividers of n.

Dividers of $m^n$ are $1,m,m^2,...,m^n$ then we have that $τ(m^n)=n+1$.

Is this correct so far?

Now we must prove that $τ(m^n)$ and $n$ are coprime, and I've though of using Bezouts theorem. Is this also a correct way?

Comment: If $m$ is composite, then $m^n$ has more divisors. E.g. $216 = 6^3$ has $16$ divisors: $1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,27,36,54,72,108,216$.

Comment: $m^{n}$ might have more distinct divisors, if say $m$ is not a prime. But there is a way to work around it, by utilizing the multiplicativity of $\tau$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

If a prime $p$ divides $n$ and $n+1$ then it divides $(n+1)-n = 1$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Remark that if  $m=\Pi p_i^{l_i}$, where $p_i$ is prime and $p_i$ and $p_j$ are coprime if $i\neq j$,  $r(m)=\Pi(l_i+1)$ this implies that $r(m^n)= \Pi(nl_i+1)$.